# Saving a state of button even after its parent view is dismissed in iOS

Tags: ios

How to save the background color state of a button after its parent view is removed. So dat the next time i click on the button after the parent view is again loaded I can change the initial color of the button.

Comment: I have many such custom button on which i write the text dynamically.. Using NSUserDefaults may be inefficient..

Comment: How many buttons do you have?

Comment: Create a singleton class that will contain the state of all your buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for `PList`.

Try this:-

**In AppDelegate.h**

```
+(NSString *)getValueFromPlist:(NSString *)key filename:(NSString *)filename;
+(NSString *)dataFilePath:(NSString *)filename;
```

**In AppDelegate.m**

```
+(NSString *)getValueFromPlist:(NSString *)key filename:(NSString *)filename
{
    NSString *path = [AppDelegate dataFilePath:filename];
    //NSLog(@"\npath - %@\n", path);
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    //NSLog(@"\nparsing- %@", dict);
    return [dict valueForKey:key];
}

+ (NSString *)dataFilePath:(NSString *)filename {

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *docDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [docDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
}
```

In **yourViewController.m**, use this code to save value in plist :-

```
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
[dict setValue:@"Your Value to be saved" forKey:@"value"];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"nameOfPlist.plist"];

[dict writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

Next time, get the value from plist and use it your code :-

```
NSString *strValue = [AppDelegate getValueFromPlist:@"value" filename:@"nameOfPlist.plist"];
```

Comment: Thanx for the answer Piyush, but I did it long back by using just an array.

Comment: @Saify: yes, you're right it's too late. But I answered it so that it may help others in future.